# Formular Field : Adding month to date gives an #Error

Tags: formula, formula-field, error, date

In a Formula Field; 
I tried to add a month to the date and subtract some other date value as follows but the formula returns me "#Error!" in the UI

```
 DATE( YEAR( reportDueDate__c ), ( MONTH( reportDueDate__c )+1 ) , DAY( reportDueDate__c) ) - 
    DATE( YEAR( reportDate__c ) , MONTH( reportDate__c ), DAY( reportDate__c) )
```

How could this adding 1 month cause an error?  **( MONTH( reportDueDate__c )+1 )**

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the reportDueDate__c value that is causing this?

Comment: @NickCook its a Date field

Comment: And the value of that date field?

Comment: @NickCook the value is "2015-08-31"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you need to look at here.  The documentation helps: https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions.htm&siteLang=en_US#date_and_time_functinons

DATE()

> Returns a date value from year, month, and day values you enter. Salesforce displays an error on the detail page if the value of the DATE function in a formula field is an invalid date, such as February 29 in a non-leap year.

MONTH()

> Returns the month, a number between 1 (January) and 12 (December) in number format of a given date.

Because Month() returns a number, there's no part of your logic that ensures it's between 1 and 12.  I'm assuming your error is occurring due to `reportDueDate__c` being December.

There are a number of common date formulas in the help too:  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm
Perhaps look at **Adding Days, Months, and Years to a Date**

Comment: Thanks @Nick Cook   I was able to get rid from #Error! with ensuring the month value is between 1 and 12,
 
if( (MONTH( reportDueDate__c )+1)  < 12 ,  expression1, expression2)

Answer (score 0):

To add a month, this worked for me:

`DATE(YEAR(Today()), MONTH(Today()), DAY(Today())) + ((365 / 12))`

I got this from the same link recommended by @Nick Cook's recommended URL:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=formula_examples_dates.htm

Comment: This one is nice but it doesn’t always return an exact date, sometimes it may vary for few days.